# how to remove white background of image in java

Tags: java, background

I have picture with white background and i want to clear the white background of my image. [This is the picture of signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BovZQ.png) and i want to use it like this in my jframe
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtuUo.png)

```
    javax.swing.JFileChooser fc=new javax.swing.JFileChooser();

    if(fc.showOpenDialog(this)==javax.swing.JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        try {
            Image image=ImageIO.read(fc.getSelectedFile());
            Image img=image.getScaledInstance(frmDoc.getWidth(), frmDoc.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            frmDoc.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: what problem do you have? what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to scan the signature from the white paper using scanner and use it in my app without background

Answer (score 0):

It is not simple and it would take more time than using external image editor and then uploading the new image. You cannot simply detect and remove the white color from background image and also it is hard to point what is part of background pixel by pixel.
Anyway you have to create a logic of detecting which (i.e.) white pixels are part of the picture and which are part of background.
I hope this at least gives you a bit more knowledge.

Comment: all of the pixels are part of the picture.